# How to use verb "have" as a subjunctive?

Tags: subjunctives, causative-have

Which one is correct?

```
I recommend him, have his teeth looked at by a dentist.
I recommend him, has his teeth looked at by a dentist.
```

First of all, something that confused me is that it appears that `subjunctive verb` grammar and `causative have` are intermingled here! 
If this is a subjunctive. As a subjunctive verb, I know we should use the base form of the verb. I doubt about the verb `have`. because we almost always have different rules about it. I also want to know if the negative sentence would be:

```
I recommend him, never have his teeth looked at by a dentist.
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I recommend (that) **he have** his teeth examined by a dentist.

This subjunctive complement for **recommend** is a clause, not an object as you have in your examples with **him**.

> I recommend that **he take** Intro Biology.

Comment: Given that both of OP's (syntactically invalid) examples include ***him***, it's worth noting *I recommend **him to have** his teeth looked at by a dentist*.

Comment: `I recommend him to have his teeth looked at by a dentist.` is this a correct sentence?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I don't understand your comment. What should be noted about that (invalid) sentence. That it, too, is invalid?

Comment: @a.toraby: No, that is not correct. You *advised* him to have his teeth checked.   **recommend** does not take a dual complement, the first an object, the second a clause.  You can recommend him for the job. But you cannot **recommend him that ....**

Comment: I mean that (despite some apparent disagreement in comments to another answer here) I have no problem with my ***him*** rephrasing above. And since (***all three***, as I now see, not just ***both***) OP's examples feature ***him***, it seems reasonable to show him a "syntactically valid" (according to my lights) version arrived at by minimal adjustment to his suggested constructions.

Comment: @FumbleFingers:  **recommend** {someone} **to** {verb} did have currency in the 18th century but was already moribund by the mid 19th.  I would characterize it as "marginal" nowadays in AmE.  I imagine that it could still be current in InE.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: Yes, I think you're right that BrE is more "accepting" of the *recommend {someone} to {verb}* construction. But at the end of the day I do accept that the "primary" advice in your answer (focus on the subjunctive ***that-*** clause, whether or not ***that*** is explicitly included) is the simplest and most useful approach for learners here. After all, that's why I upvoted in the first place, even before posting my ***him*** comment.

Comment: ***I recommend him to have his teeth looked at by a dentist.*** is simply not the same meaning as: ***I recommend he have his teeth looked at by a dentist. ***The first is like: We recommended them to go before the committee***.

Answer (score 2):

The verb recommend is used like this in  your context:

- I recommend [advise] **he have his teeth looked at by a dentist**.
- I recommend [advise] he leave now.

Recommend is never followed by an indirect object pronoun except when it is used as an action verb: **I recommended him for the job.**

The same is true for the verb suggest:

- I suggest you look up the list of verbs.
- I suggest he look up the list of verbs.

Suggest and recommend are followed in the third  person singular by the bare infinitive. I prefer not to call it subjunctive, and leave it at that for this purpose.

Comment: If I understand what you mean by *Recommend is never followed by an indirect object pronoun except when it is used as an action verb,* I disagree. There's nothing wrong with [*I recommend **you** to take*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I+recommend+you+to+take%22) *[care, this medicine, my advice...]*. And in case I'm mixing up direct/indirect objects there, *I recommend **this medicine** to you.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers First, it's the subject version of *you* that's being used in your example, not the object version of *you*. (Unlike *him* and *he* they are spelled the same, so the issue isn't apparent.) But I would drop the preposition from your own sentence. Just *I recommend you take*. What this answer is saying is that you would not say *I recommend him take* (object pronoun) but *I recommend he take* (subject pronoun).

Comment: ***I recommend you take this medicine.*** This one: "I recommend you to take this medicine" is not kosher unless you are recommending that the **you** is being recommended to a third party. As in: I recommended John to take the medicine in the clinical trial, not Mary. You recommend John to the trial givers. The first is not an action verb, the second is and is in keeping with what I said. So, you have, in fact, made my  point.

Comment: Actually, **I'm recommending you to take this medicine, and not Mary." I'm recommending you for the job.

Comment: @Jason Bassford: I don't think ***to*** in *I recommend you take care* is a preposition. It looks to me like a "verb infinitive marker". But lest we be distracted by the fact that ***you*** can be subject ***or*** object, I'll just cite [*We recommend him to take*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22we+recommend+him+to+take%22) *[whatever we suggest]*. Pedantry abounds around "fluid" verbs like ***recommend, suggest, want,*** etc.

Comment: I recommended him to take [whatever you like] is still an action verb. With an infinitive marker is still an action verb. So, what I said was correct. Mr. Chairman, I recommend him to take the  post. But: I recommend you to [take] etc. is not direct address to a person. Direct address is: I recommend you take the medicine.